# Return temp table on Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to execute a `store procedure` which contains three temp tables depending of the parameter that the user type can return one table or another but when I add the `store procedure` to my `edmx` on the function return the message `the store procedure doesn't return any columns`.

I read that you can use `SET FMTONLY OFF` but it doesn't work. Also I tried to convert my temp tables to variables table but nothing how can I solve this problem or in Entity Framework you can't work with temp tables ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to work around this by setting fmtonly off in the proc.

Something like this:

```
create or alter procedure someproc
as
begin
  if 1=0 
  begin  --fmtonly must be on
    set fmtonly off 
    create table #t2(i int, a varchar(20))
    select * from #t2
    return
  end

  create table #t(i int, a varchar(20))
  insert into #t(i,a) values (1,'hello')

  select * from #t

end
```